# class const attribute initialization

Tags: c++, oop, conventions

I have a class with a member attribute which I only set once at construction and is read-only thereafter. This attribute is not identical across all instances of this class. I would therefore like to define this attribute as `const T`.

I cannot assign a value to the attribute within the constructor's body but may only initialize its value in the constructor's initialization list. Furthermore, initialization lists are restricted to expressions. As a result, where I would have used a switch statement to assign a value to this attribute, I am forced to used a long chain of ternary operations.

I am now in the situation of either:

1. Accepting ugly/verbose initialization code to keep the attribute definition in line with its intended semantic or,
2. Defining the member attribute as `T` (so removing the `const` modifier) and initializing the attribute in the class constructor's body using a cleaner switch statement.

Which should I choose? What is the accepted or preferred norm? I am tending towards 1 because the semantic of the code is really important to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably make the initialisation neater by hiving it off into a function. It sounds like the logic is probably too long to be tidily written inside a lambda, so you could just use a static member function (or free function) for this task.

```
Foo::Foo(Bar args)
   : constMember(makeMyConstMember(args))
{}
```

Failing that, removing the `const` is an annoying but acceptable workaround. `const` is great, but clean and easy to read code is more important.

Comment: A lambda might do as well and could be written "inline" in the initializer.

Comment: @Scheff As I say it sounds like there's a long switch statement involved which would make that quite long and untidy.

Comment: @Scheff If it's extremely simple. Otherwise it will probably destroy readability.

Comment: Can we agree that it's a matter of taste? I personally used such lambda sometimes for two reasons: 1st: I didn't like to introduce yet another function for which the call is useful/valid only at one specific point. 2nd: I keep code together locally at one point. The lambda was just the tool to use statements where only expressions are allowed. With proper indentation, I didn't find it hard to read but I must admit that I never asked my colleagues about this.

Comment: @Scheff Yes, of course, but like I say if the required logic is long then most people's taste will say "let's put this elsewhere". My answer gives all these options.

Comment: I didn't intend to criticize your answer - not at all. (I gave my up-vote.)